# Combining rows in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this example `data.frame`:

```
df = data.frame(id = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g"), start = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70), end = c(15,25,35,45,55,65,75), flag = c(0,1,1,0,1,0,1))
> df
  id start end flag
1  a    10  15    0
2  b    20  25    1
3  c    30  35    1
4  d    40  45    0
5  e    50  55    1
6  f    60  65    0
7  g    70  75    1
```

It is sorted in ascending order by `df$start` and then `df$end`.
I'm looking for a function that will merge all rows with `df$flag == 1` that are not intervened by rows with `df$flag == 0`. Merged rows should have their `df$id` concatenated with a coma separator, their `df$start` should be that of the row with the `min` `df$start` and their `df$end`should be that of the row with the `max` `df$end`. And finally, `df$flag` should be 1 for them.

So for this example the return `data.frame` should be:

```
res.df = data.frame(id = c("a","b,c","d","e","f","g"), start = c(10,20,40,50,60,70), end = c(15,35,45,55,65,75), flag = c(0,1,0,1,0,1))
> res.df
   id start end flag
1   a    10  15    0
2 b,c    20  35    1
3   d    40  45    0
4   e    50  55    1
5   f    60  65    0
6   g    70  75    1
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the `end` value?  From your explanation, it sounds like it should be 35 but your `res.df` shows 25.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's fixed now.

Comment: One more question:  Will there ever be more than two rows being combined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is difficult to do with `aggregate` as the same function gets applied to each column in turn.  Multiple calls to `aggregate` could accomplish this in pieces which are then merged.  However, `data.table` allows for different aggregation functions in the same call:

```
library(data.table)
d <- data.table(df)

d[,list(id=paste(id, collapse=','), start=min(start), end=max(end)), 
  by=list(flag, cumsum(flag==0))
]
   flag cumsum  id start end
1:    0      1   a    10  15
2:    1      1 b,c    20  35
3:    0      2   d    40  45
4:    1      2   e    50  55
5:    0      3   f    60  65
6:    1      3   g    70  75
```

You do end up with a new column which may be removed if desired.  The condition on `cumsum(flag==0)` prevents any rows with `flag==0` from being combined in the aggregate, and keeps the non-consecutive `flag==1` values separate in the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution in `base` using `aggregate` and `merge`:

```
merge(merge(aggregate(start ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=min), 
           aggregate(end ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=max)
      ), 
     aggregate(id ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=paste, sep=',')
)
  flag cumsum(flag == 0) start end   id
1    0                 1    10  15    a
2    0                 2    40  45    d
3    0                 3    60  65    f
4    1                 1    20  35 b, c
5    1                 2    50  55    e
6    1                 3    70  75    g
```

The code is a bit more readable if you use `Reduce` and a list of data frames to do the merge:

```
Reduce(merge, list(aggregate(start ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=min), 
                   aggregate(end   ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=max),
                   aggregate(id    ~ flag + cumsum(flag==0), data=df, FUN=paste, sep=',')
              )
)
```